# ImportError: no module named 'umqtt.MQTTClient' but file with class exists

Tags: python-import, esp8266, micropython

I installed MicroPython v1.9.3-8 on my ESP8266 board. Here is the beginning of my main.py file:

```
from machine import Pin

led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT, value=1)

#---MQTT Sending---

from time import sleep_ms
from ubinascii import hexlify
from machine import unique_id
#import socket
from umqtt import MQTTClient

SERVER = "10.6.6.192"
CLIENT_ID = hexlify(unique_id())
TOPIC1 = b"/server/tem"
TOPIC2 = b"/server/hum"
TOPIC3 = b"/server/led"
```

The line from umqtt import MQTTClient throws an error when I reset the module:

> File "main.py", line 11, in < module >
>
> ImportError: no module named 'umqtt.MQTTClient'

[Here is my umqtt.py file](https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/12979555293536/umqtt.py).

I have the umqtt.py file uploaded to my esp8266 with webrepl. When I run:

```
import os
os.listdir()
```

I get this output:

```
>>> os.listdir()
['boot.py', 'webrepl_cfg.py', 'umqtt.py', 'main.py']
```

Since in the umqtt.py file in line 8 the class MQTTClient is defined, I do not know what am I doing wrong to get this code to work.

Comment: You may have moved on or found a solution, but it might help to know what the value of sys.path is just before the import is attempted.

Comment: Hi! What does python umqtt.py says after adding to umqtt.py the following code:    `if __name__ == "__main__":
                         print("Module umqtt")` ?

Comment: and 2nd question do you have on your esp8266 umqtt.pyc file?

Comment: Can you do a `import umqtt` and then do `print(dir(umqtt))` and post that log. Either you have a pyc file or you have your path set incorrect and have another version of `umqtt` in some other path as well

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to either specify the simple or the robust versions:

```
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient
```